# how to operate functions on view in a ListView item

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi I have a ListView with adapter.
each item has a switch and I try to use it with .setOnCheckedChangeListener.
I dont get any response (it doesnt listen)

here is my code: (I put it after the .setAdapter)

```
 for(int i=0;i<gateList.size();i++) {
                View view = gateAdapter.getView(i,null,gateListView);
                Switch gateSwitch = view.findViewById(R.id.gate_operate_switch);
                int finalI = i;
                gateSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
                    Gate gate = gateAdapter.getItem(finalI);
                    if (isChecked){
                        gate.setOperate(true );
                    }else {
                        gate.setOperate(false);
                    }
                    gateRepository.updateGate(gate);
                });

            }
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to set it up inside the adapter.  So what type of adapter? Custom adapter? Pls show how you create the adapter/adapter code.

Comment: Thanks! setting it inside the addapter did the trick